# Derivative for Matrix function

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a matrix kernel function which I am trying to find the derivative to. Function is K = c * exp[-1/2 * (P(X1 - X2))' * P(X1 -X2)] where uppercase are matrices and lower case are scalars (and ' denotes transpose). I'm trying to find dK/dP. I'm pretty rusty on matrix calculus, can anyone give me a hand here?

Thanks

Comment: Your notation is not very clear. Is $P$ a matrix? then did you mean something like $K(P) = c \exp[-\frac12 \| P(X_1 - X_2) \|^2]$? In that case you should probably write (P(X1-X2))', the transpose should be around everything and maybe a trace before it? Is P symmetric or not?

Comment: I was assuming this is a matrix valued function. If that's true I'd undelete my (by now corrected) answer. If @passerby51 assumption is correct, the derivative is just $$ D_V K = -1/2K \langle V(X_1-X_2), P(X_1-X_2)\rangle$$ with $\langle.,.\rangle$ the scalar product on the vector space of matrices.

Comment: Sorry yeah the transpose is around the whole thing. P is not symmetric.

Comment: Yeah it is a matrix valued function. I didn't quite get a chance to see your deleted answer Thomas. What was it? Thanks for the response guys.

Comment: undeleted my reply.

Comment: Sorry this is going to be kind of dumb, but Thomas, what is V?

Comment: if this is a matrix valued function, you have to take the derivative in direction of a matrix $V$. $D_V K(X) = \frac{d}{d t}K(X+tV)|_{t=0}$

Comment: (And the factor $1/2$ in my previous comment is not correct)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$Z(P)=(P(X_1-X_2))^TP(X_1-X_2)$$
If $K$ is viewed as depending only on $P$ and if you differentiate in direction $V$ you get
$$ D_V K = K*\frac{-1}{2} \left\{\frac{I-e^{-ad_{Z(P)}}}{ad_{Z(p)}}  \left[ (V(X_1-X_2))^TP(X_1-X_2) + P(X_1-X_2)^TV(X_1-X_2) \right] \right\}$$

The term on the right hand side in curly parenthesis needs explanation. It is the matrix valued function $\frac{I-e^{-ad_{Z(P)}}}{ad_{Z(P))}}$ applied to the term in square brackets. This in turn means

$$\frac{I-e^{-ad_{Z}}}{ad_{Z}}[Y] = Y-\frac{[Z,Y]}{2!} + \frac{[Z,[Z,Y]]}{3!} - \ldots$$

See, e.g., Chapter 3.3 in Brian C. Halls Book 'Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations for a derivation of the derivative of the exponential.

(Sorry for posting a too simple and wrong answer first, which is true only if $Z$ and $D_VZ $ commute).
(I don't like the $\frac{d}{dP}$ notation).

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{ \left( #1 \right) }
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{ \left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right] }
$Given a matrix and a function $\{Y,\,F\!=\!f(Y)\}\,$ the tensor-valued gradient $\left\{G=\grad FY\right\}$
is related to the Frechet Derivative $\{L_f\}$ by
$$\eqalign{
&dY = \{{\rm direction\;of\;change\;in\;}Y\}, \qquad \|Y\|\gg\|dY\| \\
&dF = G:dY \;=\; L_f(Y,dY)
    \;\doteq\; \lim_{h\to 0}\;\frac{f(Y+h\,dY)-f(Y)}{h} \\
}$$
Block-triangular matrices offer a convenient way to compute this quantity,
as has been noted by many researchers (Kenney-Laub, Najfeld-Havel, Mathias, Higham)
$$\eqalign{
f\LR{\m{Y&dY\\0&Y}} 
  &= \m{F&dF\\0&F} \\
}$$
without needing to evaluate complicated commutator expressions such as the Magnus or BCH expansions. Of course, those commutators are still there, but they are cleverly hidden inside the function evaluation.

In this particular case
$$\eqalign{
W &= X_1-X_2 \\
Y &= -\tfrac 12 W^T\LR{P^TP}W \\
dY &= -\tfrac 12 W^T\LR{dP^TP+P^TdP}W, \qquad \|P\|\gg\|dP\| \\
F &= K = c\cdot\exp(Y) \\
}$$